# Wordpress pagination issue - I set 'posts_per_page' which works for every page except for page 1 which is just showing all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following set up in my template file:

```
<div class="flex" id="allPosts">
        <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'order'             => 'DESC',
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <div class="blog-entries">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
            $featuredImg = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
        } else {
            $featuredImg = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/blk-fri.jpg';
        }  ?>

            <a class="blog-module" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="blog-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $featuredImg; ?>');">
                    <div>
                        <div class="author">By <?php the_author(); ?></div>
                        <div class="date">
                            <p><?php echo get_the_date('M'); ?></p>
                            <p><?php echo get_the_date('d'); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="blog-content">
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This functionality is working, except on page one. Every other page limits the amount of posts seen to 12 as specified in the 'posts_per_page', but page 1 is just showing every post. Ive tried searching around for a similar problem, but have come up short. I would appreciate any and all guidance on what might be happening here, thanks!

You can view the issue here: http://listingmirror.devsite.work/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imported posts from the client were all marked 'sticky' in Wordpress. This was overwriting the post_per_page argument.

Answer (score 0):

try in that form

```
    // WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'paged'                  => '12',
    'posts_per_page'         => '12',
    'posts_per_archive_page' => '12',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'title',
);

// The Query
$paged = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $paged->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $paged->have_posts() ) {
        $paged->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply on this! I applied the following. Unfortunately, all that seemed to do is make the blog load 'page 12' results no matter which page is selected in the pagination navigation. I changed the 'paged' value to $paged to restore the functionality of jumping between pages. This left me with some new arguments you outlined here but ultimately left with the same issue, which is every other page loads 12 results, while page 1 loads all posts. Still need page one to only load 12 results like the rest.

Comment: If this helps at all, I've run into a problem that seems tied to the large issue. Even on a static page when I simply want to pull in the latest posts with a basic Wordpress loop, I assign post_per_page to '3' and it is not honoring that and instead showing all posts.